# Haskell permutation function does not compile

Tags: debugging, haskell, types, compiler-errors, permutation

I'm brushing up on some Haskell and I am trying to write a permutation function that would map [1,2,3] -> [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]. I have the following -

```
permute:: [a] -> [[a]]
permute [] = []
permute list = map f list
        where
                f x = listProduct x (permute (exclude x list))
                exclude e list1 = filter (/= e) list1
                listProduct x list2 = map (x :) list2
```

The following is the error message I get -

```
permutations.hs:3:20:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for permute :: [a] -> [[a]]
          at permutations.hs:1:11
    Expected type: a -> [a]
      Actual type: a -> [[a]]
    In the first argument of `map', namely `f'
    In the expression: map f list
    In an equation for `permute':
        permute list
          = map f list
          where
              f x = listProduct x (permute (exclude x list))
              exclude e list1 = filter (/= e) list1
              listProduct x list2 = map (x :) list2
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I would try to debug, but it doesn't even compile. Any ideas?

Comment: It's debugging for you somewhat, saying that it expects `f` to be a function of type a -> [a] but is getting a type a -> [[a]]

Comment: `listProduct` anything looks like it ought to return a `[[a]]`, which would make `f` take the argument `x` and return a `[[a]]`. Perhaps try to experiment with each function independently to make sure its doing what you'd like it to.

Comment: Gilad, why is f expected to be of type (a -> [a])? by the definition of map, seems like f is entitled to map from and to totally polymorphic types -
`map                     :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f  []               =  []
map f (x:xs)            =  f x : map f xs`

Comment: You should put type signatures on `f`, `exclude` and `listProduct`. The compiler errors when you have type signatures will give you more of a clue about where you went wrong.

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive Generally a good idea, although in this particular case that requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension, and doesn't actually help any.

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on the involved list types, only:

```
permute (exclude x list)
```

is of type `[[a]]` because of the type signature of `permute`, hence

```
listProduct x (permute (exclude x list))
```

is also of type `[[a]]` by the def. of `listProduct`

```
listProduct x list2 = map (x :) list2
```

Summing up,

```
 f x = listProduct x (permute (exclude x list))
```

returns `[[a]]`, but then

```
permute list = map f list
```

applies `f` to all the elements of a `[a]`, returning a `[[[a]]]`, 
which is not the correct return type for `permute`.

## How to fix

1. Turn that `[[[a]]]` into `[[a]]` by concatenating all the lists.
2. Add an `Eq a` constraint, since you re using `/= x` in `exclude`
3. The base case currently states that the empty list has no permutations, which is wrong. 
   There is one permutation for `[]`. (Indeed, 0!=1, not 0)

Comment: Hey, so I'm not sure I agree with the last comment. We apply `f` to **each** element in `list`, not `list` as a whole; namely, we apply `f` to values of type `a`, not `[a]`. At least that was my intention.

Comment: So we should be returning `[[a]]`, not `[[[a]]]`.

Comment: @DanSok If `f` returns an `[[a]]` for each element of `list`, the result of `map f list` is `[[[a]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who may be interested - to solve this problem I needed a way to simulate iteration from imperative programming, and therefore a circular list suggested itself (essentially I have been trying to simulate a solution I wrote in javascript once which involved the same process I describe, with the single exception that I took advantage of a for loop).

```
permute [] = [[]]
permute list = [h:tail | h <- list, tail <- (permute (exclude h list))]
  where
    exclude x = filter (/= x)
```

Not necessarily the most efficient solution because `exclude` is an `O(n)` operation, but neat, and works very well as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to do this is to combine the picking and the excluding of a list item into one purely positional operation `select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]`:

```
import Control.Arrow (second)
-- second f (a, b) = (a, f b)

select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map (second (x:)) (select xs)

permute [] = [[]]    -- 1 permutation of an empty list
permute xs = [x : t | (x,rest) <- select xs, t <- permute rest]
```

To "debug"-develop your program you could [define each internal function on its own](https://www.google.com/#q=lambda-lifting) as a global one, and see whether the bits and pieces fit together:

```
> let exclude e list1 = filter (/= e) list1
> let listProduct x list2 = map (x :) list2
> let f x = listProduct x (permute (exclude x list)) 
<interactive>:1:25: Not in scope: `permute' -- permute is not defined yet!!
<interactive>:1:44: Not in scope: `list'    -- need to pass 'list' in
> let f list x = listProduct x (undefined (exclude x list))
                                ---------   -- use a stand-in for now
> let permute [] = [] ; permute list = map (f list) list
> :t permute                           ---
permute :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [[[t]]]    -- one too many levels of list!
```

So they do fit together, it's just that the result is not what we want. Instead of changing what `f` produces (as the compiler suggested), we can change how its results are combined. `concat` removes one level of list nesting (it is the monadic `join` for the `[]` type constructor):

```
> let permute [] = [] ; permute list = concatMap (f list) list
> :t permute                           ---------
permute :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [[t]]      -- much better
```

Incidentally, were you *not* to specify the type signature yourself, it would compile and report the `[a] -> [[[a]]]` type back to you.

More importantly, by bringing the `/=` into the picture, you needlessly require an `Eq a` constraint on the items in a list: `permute :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]`.